# Highcharts and jQuery animate: Snaps back to original size; only works when window is resized

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate, highcharts

Frustrating issue... I'm rendering a chart via Highstock; works fine. I'm then using jquery animate to shrink the size of the chart when clicking on a certain link; also works fine. However, once the animation is complete, the chart just snaps back to the original size. When I resize the browser window, the chart goes to the right size (i.e. what it should be after the animation completes). It's almost like the chart needs to redraw; but I've tried calling the redraw option to no avail. Thanks for any help.

Here's my code:

```
 $("#PriceChart").animate({
   width: "250px"
 }, 1500 );
```

And my chart:

```
var pricechart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    pricechart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'PriceChart',
            margin: 1
        },
 yadda yadda yadda
```

**Update** jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GyY9m/8/

Comment: How Does it Looks Like when Using `.width()` And `.Height()` ???? will you be able to create a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Same thing... nothing happens until I resize the browser window manually... Will try to set up a js fiddle.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GyY9m/8/  As you can see, the width just snaps back to normal once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Because inner div `.highcharts-container` have fixed width and height. You can for example set:

```
#PriceChart {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```